# Put string to the RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a very long string, but when I try to assign it to the RichTextBox, it takes a long time, for example:

```
string s = "very long string";
RichTextBox obj = new RichTextBox ();
obj.Text = s;
```

Is there another way to put string in a faster way?

Comment: Is your rich textbox on the form? You can use textbox too; just enable multi line property and then set the text to the textbox from your variable. I just sent 5000 characters to a field in like 1 second, how long is it taking?

Comment: why not RichTextBox1.Text = s; ?

Comment: how long the string s is?

Comment: What do you mean `it take along time` ?

Comment: OP means `a long time` rather than `along time` I think.....

Comment: @sajanyamaha : I think OP is doing same thing as you are suggesting

Comment: what are you doing with obj once you have the text in it? are you displaying it on a form?

Answer (score 0):

First try to find out what makes the delay, is it about the writing to the
screen, or the creation of the added text.
As it is about the latter, then try a stringbuilder in between to create a
strings

Comment: it should be in comment section I believe :)

Comment: but i'm not getting add comment option for that specific question

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not what you are looking for but a guess on the fly. In case you are worried that your form hangs while the long text(string) is being assigned to the richtextbox and you can't operate anything, you can try assigning text in a thread instead to keep working with your main form. Sample code given below.

```
private void SetTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string longText = "Very Long Text";
    Thread t = new Thread(() => AssignLongText(longText));
    t.Start();
}

private void AssignLongText(longText)
{
    Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.AppendText(text)));
}
```

If my beer got over in home will surely try to see this post again :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: you may run into cross thread errors with this answer. you would need to create a delegate for the assign long text routine and then check the textbox's invokerequired property to ensure that you are on the GUI thread when doing the text insertion.

Comment: Just ignored the cross thread thing.......my folly. I have updated the answer to address your comment